# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSLog unless the NSString is manipulated and printed first

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get a feel for objective C, so I wrote the code below to try to print the contents of a web page:

```
id url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse* resp = [NSURLResponse new];
NSURLConnection* conn = [NSURLConnection new];
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&resp error:&error];
NSString* html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//    printf([[html substringToIndex:50] cString]);
NSLog(html);
```

when I run this as-is, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the NSLog line.  When I uncomment the second-last line it works.  If I change the printf to an assignment it stops working again.  I'm clearly missing something here about how the memory model works, but it seems like the commented out line shouldn't make any difference since it's creating a new string and it **really** seems like printf vs an assignment shouldn't make a difference.  In the Xcode debugger when the program crashes I can see that `html` does contain the HTML string I wanted to print.

Comment: Does that html string include a `%`?  You probably want `NSLog(@"%@", html)`.  *Edit:* I just made a test program with your code, and I get the same results.  Using a proper format for `NSLog` fixes it - and gcc even gives a warning for your original code, so that should be a sign to you in the future.

Comment: Note that the same applies to `printf()`: it should be `printf("%s", …)`. Both `NSLog()` and `printf()` expect a **format string** as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks!  That solves my immediate issue, but do you know why the printf would make it work?  substringToIndex is producing a new string, so `html` should be the same regardless of whether that line is there

Comment: Since you were not specifying a format, `NSLog()` got whatever was on the stack for the arguments that you didn’t specify. Calling `printf()` probably modified the stack so that `NSLog()` did find valid data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try NSLog(@"%@", html) instead of just NSLog (html)